# Neo4j technique / constraint to prevent cycles while building a graph?

Tags: c#, graph, neo4j, directed-acyclic-graphs

When building a graph, one can end up creating a cycle.
For example:  peter -> bill -> tom -> peter; peter -> peter

Is there any technique, or constraint, from Neo4j which rejects creating a node/relationship if a cycle will be created? In other words, how can one ensure the graph is a DAG at all times?

I am working with C# if a solution requires implementation at the application level.